# Swift: [__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[1]'

Tags: swift

I have a UITextView and I want to store this text in a NSDictionary.

I have this piece of code:

```
 var imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(photoInfo["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] as UIImage, 100.0)

        var description = photoDesc.text

        println(description)

        var parameters: NSDictionary = ["user":"admin", "desc" : description, "image" : imageData]

        println(parameters)
```

**println()** outputs "description" correctly, but my code crash in this line:  var parameters: `NSDictionary = ["user":"admin", "desc" : description, "image" : imageData]`

with this error:

```
[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[1]'
```

If I remove "desc" key from NSDictionary, I don't get any error.

Any idea ?

**SOLVED:**

```
var description: String = photoDesc.text
```

Comment: Have you checked to see if description is nil?

Comment: Why not store it in a Swift dictionary? i.e. Dictionary<AnyObject>

Comment: I mean Dictionary<String, AnyObject>. Can't edit my comment anymore.

Comment: Thank you Millie, I've solved with: var description: String = photoDesc.text

Answer (score 2):

You can't store `nil` in `NSDictionary`. Pass `NSNull` for your `description` instead.

Comment: `Unexpected interface name 'NSNull': expected expression`

Comment: @AndrewKoster `NSNull()`

Comment: NSDictionary* eventData = @{
      @"selectedItem": NSNull(),
    };

Comment: @AndrewKoster are you using swift or objective c? It works on `https://online.swiftplayground.run/`. Go try it there. `var parameters: NSDictionary = ["user":NSNull()]`. With your code I get stuff like `string literals in Swift are not preceded by an '@' sign`

Comment: @AndrewKoster if you are using objective c, please remove your downvote. This question is about swift and only tagged swift.